# Date pipe in Angular formControlName

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-pipe, date-pipe

Can someone please guide me to implement date pipe in angular 8 with formControlName

**train.component.html**

```
<mat-grid-tile colspan=1 rowspan=1>
    <div class="train-control">
        <input type="text" formControlName="{{ 'apprTimestamp' | date:'medium' }}">
    </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

But does not not seemed to work. Can some one please guide me.

Exception

```
TrainComponent.html:58 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "apprTimestamp" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:5737)
    at DatePipe.transform (common.js:6877)
    at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.js:34381)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35155)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35090)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:36112)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:36055)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TrainComponent.html:60)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36043)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35055)
```

Thanks !

Comment: You pass 'apprTimestamp' as a literal string, of course it can't be converted to time!

Comment: When I pass this as ```<input type="text" formControlName="{{ apprTimestamp | date:'medium' }}">``` , I get ```TrainComponent.html:58 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
    at _throwError (forms.js:2749)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2573)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:6318)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6969)```

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a datetime to a form control *name*? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: apprTimestamp is value something like 2018-01-01 in string format , my bad I should have mentioned it

Comment: That is not the point everyone else is making, you are using a literal string `'apprTimestamp'` in your code and *not* the variable with the assigned value. That is because you enclosed your variable name with single quotes.

Comment: I think I got it now . Thanks for the inputs

Answer (score 4):

You can use the datepipe in the component as well, and modify the date from there. This will only work once, with a preset date. But you are also not including anything else in your question, so we can completely omit that.

So I suggest the following:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
```

Inject it in the constructor and then use::

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private datePipe: DatePipe) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    field1: [this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'medium')]
  })
}
```

Then remove the pipe from the template.

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vaquvy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: With typed controls, your control is supposed to be `FormControl<Date>` and then you cannot use `this.datePipe.transform` as value because it returns a `string`.

Answer (score -5):

Exclude the '' with the variable containing the timestamp value, if you really want to assign the date value to the formControlName.

```
<input type="text" name="someName" formControlName="{{ apprTimestamp | date:'medium' }}">
```

Comment: Does not work , and fails with the exception ```TrainComponent.html:58 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
    at _throwError (forms.js:2749)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2573)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:6318)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6969)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:6892)
    ```